# Invalid transport, must be an object with a log method winston mongodb logging

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, winston

I want to store my error logs in mongoDB collection. I am using winston & winston -mongoDB.

Getting the error:

> throw new Error('Invalid transport, must be an object with a log
>   method.'); Error: Invalid transport, must be an object with a log
>   method.

Here is the code in logger file.
    Here is my code:
    import appRoot from 'app-root-path';
    import {
        createLogger,
        transports,
        format,
    } from 'winston';

```
import * as winston from 'winston';


require('winston-mongodb');


const options = {
    fileInfo: {
        level: 'info',
        filename: `${appRoot}/logs/info.log`,
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: true,
        maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
        maxFiles: 5,
        colorize: false,
        timestamp: true,
    },
    mongoDB: {
        db: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test',
        collection: 'log',
        level: 'info',
        storeHost: true,
        capped: true,
    },
};

winston.add(winston.transports.MongoDB, options.mongoDB);


const logger = createLogger({
    format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
        }),
        format.json()
    ),
    transports: [
        new transports.File(options.fileInfo)
    ],
});

logger.stream = {
    write: (message, encoding) => {
        logger.info(message);
    },
};

export default logger;
```

Versions:

```
 "mongoose": "^5.2.6",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "winston": "^3.0.0",
    "winston-mongodb": "^4.0.3",
    mongodb@3.1.1
```

Answer (score 45):

I had the same issue, what I did was to replace this statement:

```
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'logfile.log' });
```

to this:

```
winston.add(new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logfile.log' }));
```

This happens in the latest major update of winston i.e 3.x.x and above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I confirm, this helped in my case. As usual, useless change in api when upgrading to new version of the library, that brokes entire app.

Comment: I had exactly this in mind, and your answer here confirmed it. Yes this worked perfectly except I did not see anything in terminal, got the logfile though. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

### Updated Answer:

You need to add mongo transport in winston initialization.

Try this code:

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.MongoDB({
            db: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',
            collection: 'log',
            level: 'info',
            storeHost: true,
            capped: true,
        })
    ]
});
```

Check the log collection in test DB.

Make sure you have:

```
logger.info("Test log!")
```

Hope this solves your query!

Comment: Hi jack, console & file transports were working fine. My issue is in mongodb transport i.e. logging to mongodb collections.

Comment: Okay, let me check.

Comment: @saurabhujjainwal I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: Thanks. Can u also help with logging meta data to mongoDb.

Comment: What kind of Meta-data?

Comment: Send that userid in logger for example: `logger.error("Error on user"+userId);`

Comment: @saurabhujjainwal, can you approve the answer if it solves your query.

Answer (score 5):

This is for that latest version as of now.

"mongoose": "^5.11.10",
"winston": "^3.3.3",
"winston-mongodb": "^5.0.5"

I faced the same issue. This is what fixed my issue

```
winston.add(
  new winston.transports.File({ filename: "logfile.log", level: "error" })
);
winston.add(
  new winston.transports.MongoDB({ db: "mongodb://localhost/vidly" })
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar problem so what I did is alter the `package.json` with the line from `"winston": "^3.0.0"` to `"winston": "2.*"` then entered this command `npm install -save winston` in the command line

Answer (score 0):

`winston.configure({transports: [new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logfile.log' }) ]});`

This worked for me. Hope it helps for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning `nodeJS` and this `winston` logging issue happened. so the solution proposed before was reconfirmed and worked well.

The changes I did was from

```js
winston.add(
    winston.transports.File,
    { filename: "logfile.log" }
);
```

To:

```js
winston.add(new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logfile.log' }));
```

My packages versions are as follow:

```json
{
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "config": "^3.3.7",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "fawn": "^2.1.5",
    "font": "^0.0.4",
    "joi-objectid": "^4.0.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.8",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "winston": "^3.6.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me if I replace :

```
<br>
   winston.add(azureApplicationInsightsLogger, {....<br>
with :<br>
   winston.add(new azureApplicationInsightsLogger(), {...<br>
and <br>
   winston.add(winston.transports.Console, {...<br>
with : <br>
   winston.add(new winston.transports.Console(), {...
```

Answer (score 0):

ran into the same issue.
here's what worked for me, in package.json, set winston versions to

"winston": "^2.4.7",
"winston-mongodb": "^5.1.1"